# How can I split the strings and get only the first part of it?

Tags: python, string, list, split, duplicates

I have a list in python like so:

```
l=['1:a', '2:b' '1:c', '3:d', '4:d' ]
```

I want to remove duplicates from list.. but not whole index. I want to remove duplicates from first parameter of each index:

```
list(set(l)).split(':')[0]
```

But I know this is not correct. I want the following result:

```
>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I have `1:a` and `1:c` so I want to capture just `1`.

Comment: You can't declare a list using this syntax: l=[1:a, 2:b 1:c, 3:d, 4:d ]. This syntax is reserved for dictionaries

Comment: You all collapsing me??? I corrected the question !!!

Comment: We are human... All of us can make an error undesired... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only unique values and you are worried about the Order, then you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), like this

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> l = ['1:a', '2:b' '1:c', '3:d', '4:d']
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(item.split(':')[0] for item in l).keys())
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

If you are not worried about the Order, then you can use `set` like this

```
>>> set(item.split(':')[0] for item in l)
{'1', '3', '4', '2'}
```

If you want the results to be in the sorted order, then you can use `sorted` function, like this

```
>>> sorted(set(item.split(':')[0] for item in l), key=int)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

It converts the individual items to integers when it compares them during the sorting.

You can also use set comprehension here, like this

```
>>> sorted({item.split(':')[0] for item in l}, key=int)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: As a note, you can do a set comprehension instead of a `set()` call with a generator expression, i.e.: `sorted({item.split(':')[0] for item in l}, key=int)`.

Comment: @Lattyware Oh yeah, I totally forgot about that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you should probably make a new list taking the number from the string

```
numbers = [i.split(":")[0] for i in l]
```

This is list comprehension, but you could use a for loop.

Then, use a set to remove duplicates

```
no_duplicates = list(set(numbers))
```

If you are worried about the order of the list, sort it like so:

```
no_duplicates.sort(key=int)
```

Comment: using sort is not going to order the list as it were originally, if it does it will be by chance

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It won't but the ordereddict method was in the accepted answer, and I couldn't think of another simpler way